# CF_STAGING_TIMEOUT for deploying Shiny app on Bluemix with Cloud Foundry

Tags: r, shiny, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have a Shiny app that runs as expected locally, and I am working to deploy it to Bluemix using Cloud Foundry. I am using [this buildpack](https://github.com/beibeiyang/cf-buildpack-r).

The default staging time for apps to build is 15 minutes, but that is not long enough to install R and the packages needed for my app. If I try to push my app with the defaults, I get an error about running out of time:

```
Error restarting application: sherlock-topics failed to stage within 15.000000 minutes
```

I changed my `manifest.yml` to increase the staging time:

```
applications:  
- name: sherlock-topics
  memory: 728M
  instances: 1
  buildpack: git://github.com/beibeiyang/cf-buildpack-r.git
  env:
    CRAN_MIRROR: https://cran.rstudio.com
    CF_STAGING_TIMEOUT: 45
    CF_STARTUP_TIMEOUT: 9999
```

Then I also changed the staging time for the CLI before pushing:

```
cf set-env sherlock-topics CF_STAGING_TIMEOUT 45
cf push sherlock-topics
```

What happens then is that the app tries to deploy. It installs R in the container and installs packages, but only for about 15 minutes (a little longer). When it gets to the first new task (package) after the 15 minute mark, it errors but with a different, sadly uninformative error message.

```
Staging failed
Destroying container
Successfully destroyed container

FAILED
Error restarting application: StagingError
```

There is nothing in the logs but info about the libraries being installed and then `Staging failed`.

Any ideas about why it isn't continuing to stage past the 15-minute mark, even after I increase `CF_STAGING_TIMEOUT`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The platform operator controls the hard limit for staging timeout and application startup timeout.  `CF_STAGING_TIMEOUT` and `CF_STARTUP_TIMEOUT` are cf cli configuration options that tell the cli how long to wait for staging and app startup.

See docs here for reference:

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/large-app-deploy.html#consid_limits

As an end user, it's not possible to exceed the hard limits put in place by your platform operator.

Comment: I've been looking at the page a lot! It says "Changing the timeout setting for the cf CLI does not change the timeout limit for Cloud Foundry server-side jobs such as staging or starting applications. You must change server-side timeouts in the manifest." That means my `manifest.yml` file, right?

Comment: No, `manifest.yml` is just another way to supply configuration to the cf cli.  By "server-side" they mean that the operator need to change this, typically by updating their Bosh manifests and running `bosh deploy`.  As a user, you cannot make these changes.

Comment: Hmmm, boy, this is not going to work then. Maybe I will try to deploy this using a Docker image.

Comment: @JuliaSilge, Have you had a chance to solve this? It looks like my application compilation time exceeds 15 minutes limit even if I increase memory to 8GB (my org limit).

Comment: @AlexeyChekanov No, I did not unfortunately. :/

Comment: @JuliaSilge, Thank you!

Comment: @AlexeyChekanov if you are only hitting the staging limit, you could try a docker image. You can build one with `cf local`, it's a plugin for the cf CLI that will use buildpacks to generate images locally in Docker. You can then deploy that to CF using `cf push -o`. You could also look at using `pack` and Cloud-Native Buildpacks. These are the next generation of buildpacks but are also fairly new so you'd need to check if your buildpacks are supported. Either way, you'll have a docker image with no staging time because everything is pre-built.

Comment: @DanielMikusa, I get the following error: None of the buildpacks detected a compatible application. Error: failed to build: exit status 222. I got a list of supported buildpacks with `cf buildpacks`, and it includes the `swift_buildpack` indicated in my `manifest.yml` file. Maybe you know, why the `cf local` doesn't see it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is going to use the list of "official" buildpacks that are supported by Cloud Foundry. Your CF instance can have other buildpacks added. The one you mentioned, `swift_buildpack` isn't in the official list. Not a big deal, you're just going to need the `-b` flag when you stage to tell it where to fetch the buildpack. The value for the `-b` argument is either a local path or URL to the download zip, or it can be a URL to the Git repository.

Comment: @DanielMikusa, Yes! It worked with `cf local stage <NAME> -b https://github.com/IBM-Swift/swift-buildpack`. Thank you!

Comment: @DanielMikusa, Do I need anything to run it locally? Unfortunately, can't make it run with  `cf local run`. Tried different ports with `-p`,

Comment: It's going to need Docker to run locally. You might just try doing `cf local export` and generating a docker image. Then you can `docker run` like normal or `cf push -o` to push the docker image. You can also `cf local push` to deploy directly to your CF environment, I think newer `cf` cli's also have a `cf push` flag to push a droplet (the tgz `cf local` generates).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same exact issue. I was also trying to deploy a shinyR app with a quite a number of dependencies.

The trick is to add the `num_threads` property to `r.yml` file. This will definitely speed up the build time.

Here's how one might look:

```
packages:
 - packages: 
    - name: bupaR
    - name: edeaR
   num_threads: 8
```

See https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/r/index.html for more info